# Android REST api (JSON array) to Couchbase Lite

Tags: android, json, rest, couchbase-lite

I have an android application, which fetch data from REST api and save it to arraylist. But now I want to save data from REST api to Couchbase Lite. How can I do this? One more thing is, if data in REST api change, then the change also save in Couchbase Lite. Please help.

Here is my REST api JSON array data..

```
[
{
    "ID": "1001",
    "VAT": 0,
    "barCode": "1023sewe",
    "catagoryName": "Mobile",
    "name": "Samsung Galaxy A5",
    "purchasingPrice": 20000,
    "quantity": 5,
    "sellingPrice": 25000
},
{
    "ID": "1002",
    "VAT": 0,
    "barCode": "215qwqw",
    "catagoryName": "Mobile",
    "name": "Iphone S5",
    "purchasingPrice": 40000,
    "quantity": 3,
    "sellingPrice": 45000
}
]
```

Comment: Couchbase Server itself uses a REST API. If you want to sync Couchbase lite, use Couchbase Server. Also, have you read any documentation? Tried anything? There is no code in your question.

Comment: I am using MySQL database. So how can I use this database in couchbase server?

Comment: If you want to sync with anything other than couchbase server, then you need to write a custom android SyncAdapter. Which is more work than you probably want to do. Syncing data between clients and servers is not trivial

Answer (score -3):

You can perform insert and update operations in Couchbase lite. Follow this link that explains the CRUD operations.
        http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/training/build-first-android-app/do-crud/index.html

Insert sample

```
private String createDocument(Database database) {
    // Create a new document and add data
    Document document = database.createDocument();
    String documentId = document.getId();
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("name", "Big Party");
    map.put("location", "My House");
    try {
            // Save the properties to the document
            document.putProperties(map);
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error putting", e);
    }
    return documentId;
}
```

Update sample

```
private void updateDoc(Database database, String documentId) {
   Document document = database.getDocument(documentId);
   try {
       // Update the document with more data
       Map<String, Object> updatedProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       updatedProperties.putAll(document.getProperties());
       updatedProperties.put("eventDescription", "Everyone is invited!");
       updatedProperties.put("address", "123 Elm St.");
       // Save to the Couchbase local Couchbase Lite DB
       document.putProperties(updatedProperties);
   } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
           Log.e(TAG, "Error putting", e);
   }
}
```